# When running sfdx force:apex:test:run we get the error "Your request exceeded the time limit for processing. connection was cancelled here"

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, force-cli, sfdx-error

We have test classes that we are running from the Salesforce CLI. If we run them from the Salesforce UI, the tests all pass fine.

When running the same test classes from the CLI, however, most of the tests pass, but a few do not.

We run:

```
sfdx force:apex:test:run --testlevel RunLocalTests --codecoverage --resultformat human --wait 30 -u $org_username
```

The test classes start running. Most pass. For those that fail, we get the following error:

MyTestClassName.**null**...Fail..."Your request exceeded the time limit for processing. connection was cancelled here"

This is a mystery for several reasons:

1. The Test Classes that fail from the command line all pass when run as part of a Validation or Deployment from the UI.
2. Only a few of the test classes among many have this error.
3. If you run the failing test classes individually from the CLI, then they pass.
4. The test classes that pass are listed with a function name instead of .null. So a passing class will consistently be listed as: `MyPassingClassName.myFunctionName`. But a failing class will consistently be listed as `MyFailingClassName.null`.

Has anyone else run into this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we've had this problem in our packages. It happens when too many large unit tests try to run at once. The primary solution is to set @isTest(isParallel=false) to all of your test classes. This will increase runtime, but also eliminate this particular error (as well as UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW errors).

Comment: does @IsTest(IsParallel=false) actually work? Thought this was a missing feature https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdh6qUAB/parallel-tests-option-isparallel-on-the-istest-annotation-to-exclude-tests

If so, what does it do?

Comment: Would it be different then having the "Disable Parallel Apex Testing" option enabled? Because I faced the same issue as asked in the question when running test with sfdx against a full-copy sandbox where the "Disable Parallel Apex Testing" option enabled.

Comment: @tak971 How long are your tests taking? I've never heard of this problem when not running in parallel (which can cause extreme resource contention, which I presumed led to this error).

Comment: @sfdcfox, when I Query the ApexTestResult, the RunTime field is empty. I should also mention that those test have seeAllData=true because they use ConnectApi Namespace classes.