# "Connection was cancelled here" error NOT related to parallel testing

Tags: unit-test

I have a simple Custom VF Controller with a constructor and a single method, and an accompanying test class which I have inherited.  Nothing special; the controller queries some records and inserts some data; the test class creates test data and runs the controller method.  The test passes.  However, if I run the test class with coverage, I get the error "Could not run tests on class 01po... because: connection was cancelled here".  [This question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/354496/when-running-sfdx-forceapextestrun-we-get-the-error-your-request-exceeded-th) states that this is an issue with parallel testing, however:

1. I'm running a single test class, containing a single test method; parallel should not matter
2. I've disabled parallel tests
3. I can see the test pass after about 13 seconds after it starts running (when the spinner appears) on the "Apex Test Execution" page (click the test in the upper portion while the test is running, and you can see results for the tests completed so far).  The test keeps spinning for several more minutes before failing.

Here's the Test Execution page after clicking on the running test, 20 seconds in:
[image: Screenshot of Apex Test Execution page]
And here it is after the failure.  Note that the only test method is listed as passing, while th failing.
[image: Screenshot of Apex Test Execution page]

Clearly the test is passing long before the test "fails", and this error only happens when running with coverage.  I suspect the error is occurring while the system tries to record coverage.  I'm fairly certain no one else is running unit tests in this org while I am.  Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 2):

Since this seems to be related to coverage data, I tried clearing all test data (Dev Console > Test > Clear Test Data, then querying `ApexCodeCoverageAggregate` using ToolingAPI and deleting all matched records).  The test completed successfully.  I don't know if this was just chance, or if clearing the existing coverage data actually fixed the issue, but it seems worth trying if this error occurs.